# Whether the ARP table is based on IP or Interface?

Tags: arp

Is the arp table based on IP or based on network interface?

I have a VM, it has an Interface with `10.211.55.7`, when I show the arp, it shows:

[image]

[image: enter image description here2]

I want to know if the ARP table data is divided by IP or Network Adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, each interface has its own ARP table, mapping IPv4 addresses to L2 MAC addresses.

Comment: if the interface have two IP address. there will store different segment IP's MAC address, right?

Comment: @244boy Not usually but that may be host-specific. It wouldn't make too much sense though as the L2 that ARP maps the traffic to doesn't care about the IP addresses.